# awk calculate sum of 2nd column and percentage wrt sum and print

Tags: bash, awk

Hi I have a file with two columns in it i want to get sum of last column and calculate percentage of each value given in last column wrt to total sum and print it.
Sample file

```
$ cat /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/file.csv  
5,10266  
7,8009854  
0,1441242  
1,6722341  
Total,16183703
```

so total sum of last column is 16183703.
Required output

```
Failure_Code,FAILURE_SUM,Ratio  
5,10266,0.06%  
7,8009854,49.49%  
0,1441242,8.91%  
1,6722341,41.54%  
Total,16183703,100.00%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{print "Failure_Code,FAILURE_SUM,Ratio"}{a[++i]=$1;b[i]=$2};/Total/{for(j=1;j<=i;++j)printf "%s,%d,%0.2f%\n",a[j],b[j],(b[j]*100/$2)}' file
```

Output:

```
Failure_Code,FAILURE_SUM,Ratio
5,10266,0.06%
7,8009854,49.49%
0,1441242,8.91%
1,6722341,41.54%
Total,16183703,100.00%
```

Comment: Note that this solution relies on reading the whole file into RAM and it will fail for large files. My solution adresses this by reading the file twice, reducing performance, sudo_O's solution is IMHO superior to both other approaches since it reads the file only once and still does not need to store the whole file in memory.

Comment: @sg-lecram It can be but there's also a price for performance. Even with large files one still has to decide if using a buffered solution is ideal or not. Also, don't you know that `tac` stores *whole* output on a buffer as well? And if it (tac) would use temporary files to compensate I think the solution has gone far already.

Comment: @konsolebox: Well you are right, I did not consider the way `tac` works when comparing the solutions, in this case calling `tac` twice would also result in buffering the input twice (at the same time since the two instances are linked via the pipeline). So maybe your solution is the fastes, mine the robustest and sudo_O's the prettiest. ;-)

Comment: I don't think file size will be an issue for the OP *(at least they never mentioned extremely large files)*, it's good that all three approaches have been demonstrated, +1.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you have 3 approaches: buffer the input (like **[Fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18696310/1066031)** and **[konsolebox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18696449/1066031)**), read the file twice (like **[sg-lecram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18696301/1066031)**) or use `tac` to pipe the input in reverse and pipe back through `tac` after performing the transformation. I usually take the `tac` approach for this kind of thing:

```
$ tac file | awk 'NR==1{t=$2}{$3=sprintf("%.2f%",$2/t*100)}1' FS=, OFS=, | tac
5,10266,0.06%
7,8009854,49.49%
0,1441242,8.91%
1,6722341,41.54%
Total,16183703,100.00%
```

To add the header just print it in the `END` block.

Comment: `tac`, a-ha! Super. +1.

Comment: Hi, getting proper output but i am not getting 4th line 1,6722341,41.54%. Please cross verify and suggest.

Comment: I believe it is you that needs to *cross verify*. Given your input file this will produce the output you expected, please closely look at the file you posted and your actual file. If you are note seeing `1,6722341,41.54%` then what are you seeing?

Comment: I like the `tac`, it reduces disc I/O compared to my solution and still reads the file only once - all for the cost of a little process overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to do this in just one run of `awk` in general (**edit:** *but actually [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18696314/2451238)*), but you can process the same file twice - once to get the overall sum and twice to calculate the percentages:

```
awk '
 BEGIN{ # initialization
  FS=","
  OFS=FS
  print "Failure_Code","FAILURE_SUM","Ratio"
 }
 FNR==NR{ # first run
  total_sum=$2
  next
 }
 { # second run
  print $0,100*$2/total_sum"%"
 }
' /cygdrive/KPI/test/file.csv /cygdrive/KPI/test/file.csv
```

Comment: Hi, by running your script i am getting below output  
Failure_Code,FAILURE_SUM,Ratio  
5,10266,5,500,13%  
7,8009854,12,1200,13%  
0,1441242,12,1200,13%  
1,6722341,13,1300,13%  
Total,16183703,13,1300,13%  
,13,100.00%  
However we can remove additional 4,5 columns by using cut command but here it is giving percentage value wrong. As you can see for every line i am getting 13%.

Comment: @user2761031: I fixed a typo (used to have an additional `,` instead of the required `/` when calculation the percentages.

Comment: @user2761031: Due to the bad formatting I did not notice the Total row was already included in the input. Please check out the new version.